# Plot area padding to prevent symbols from being truncated. (Core Plot)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

In Core Plot for iOS, is there a way to add some sort of padding to a plot area, as opposed to a plot area frame? When using plot symbols, the symbols can be truncated if they fall on an axis line or boundary of the frame. Admittedly, I understand why this is the case when plotting a non-zero sized circle as a data symbol, but I'm curious if there's a way to add some padding to prevent this.

Or maybe there's a way to do with the axis ranges, but if so I haven't figured out the magic combination other than creating axis ranges that are "magically" large enough to account for the size of these symbols.

In the attached screenshot, the x-axis represents a week. Any data point for the first day will be truncated because it's getting drawn right on the y-axis. Ideally, I'd like this data point drawn just "a bit inside". (Which really means I want the x-axis range to increase by just enough to take this in to account.)

Likewise for the y-axis. A value of '0' plots right on the x-axis.

I don't really want the axis to show a range wider than required (i.e. I don't want the y-axis to go -1, for example.)

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some sample code from the "Control Chart" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app:

```
// Adjust visible ranges so plot symbols along the edges are not clipped
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [[plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy] autorelease];
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [[plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy] autorelease];

x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = yRange.location;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = xRange.location;

x.visibleRange = xRange;
y.visibleRange = yRange;

x.gridLinesRange = yRange;
y.gridLinesRange = xRange;

[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.05)];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.05)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
```

You can adjust the expansion factor as needed based on the size of the graph and plot symbols.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that definitely works. Can you a explain a bit why it works? How can the range be expanded yet the data points still be correct without any change on my part? And for that matter, how come my custom labels more or less work, but if I increase the expansion factor than the labels start to get really bunched up.

Comment: The `visibleRange` limits the part of the axis that is actually drawn and the `gridLinesRange` does the same for the grid lines. We expand the plot ranges to make the plot area (the layer that contains all plot drawing) big enough to contain the symbols that hang outside the axes.

Comment: @EricSkroch #Scatter I have created custom labels of Y axis (0,50,100,150,200,250,300) and respective data points values are 18.63, 29.32, 24.31, 33.68, 136.23, 128.44, 126.20 and have created X axis as (Mon, ....SUN) and consider respective data points (0,1,2...6). Total 7 points we are drawing.But manually I have given distance less that 50 (majorIntervalLength) so that all the y labels are shown without scrolling the graph. I am facing the respective y data values points are not lying with respect to y labels position. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/186007808/ScreenShotDescription.png

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri Ask a new question instead of commenting on a  question that is over a year old. We'll need more detail about your code than you can provide in a comment.

Comment: @EricSkroch: I think that It could be solved by comment. I am here again explaining it to you: Basically I have created custom labels for for X,Y Axis and if I create Y axis labels (0,50,100.....300) through majorIntervalLength (=50) instead of custom. It will take huge space and all labels values are not shown to screen. So I have created them as a custom by specifying their tick location value. But respected y data values are drawing plot by considering 50 (majorIntervalLength). As shown in image with their original X,Y point of plot. You can match Y position with respect to Y labels value.

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri The comments aren't the place for a discussion like this, especially since it sounds like your problem isn't related to this question. Ask a new question.

Comment: @EricSkroch I have got solutions of my problem. Basically I was not setting appropriate values in "plotSpace.xRange" & "plotSpace.yRange". Anyways thanks for your quick response and surely I will ask question in next time, if I face something which will liable for it. :)

Comment: Can any please let me know what is plotSpace object here?

Comment: In this case it's `CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;`. Every plot is associated with a plot space that defines the mapping between the data and the view.

Answer (score 0):

Only this solved for me, values aligned properly from both sides(leading and trialing)

```
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.2]];
```